# Find IP and Gateway using Python Script

Tags: python, linux

I'm new to python, I have crated following small script, I just need to improve code if possible simple instead complicated.

```
import subprocess
import StringIO
import re

ip_r_l=subprocess.Popen("ip r l",shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
s = StringIO.StringIO(ip_r_l)

for line in s:
        if "default" in line:
                gw = re.search(r'\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b',line).group(0)

        if "src" in line:
                ip = re.search(r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3} $',line).group(0)
                ip = ip.rstrip()


print "Gatway: %r" % gw
print "IPaddr: %r" % ip
```

Comment: have you tried this guy? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pynetinfo/0.1.9
 or this http://thiagodefreitas.com/blog/2010/11/19/ip-netmask-gateway-python-unix/ ?

Comment: @AndreiSfat the link is nice, thanks, but any improvement in my code ? any suggestion are welcome..

Comment: Hi, this sort of question is sort of off-topic here. You'd be better served by asking on [codereview.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import subprocess, shlex
strs = subprocess.check_output(shlex.split('ip r l'))
gateway = strs.split('default via')[-1].split()[0]
ip  = strs.split('src')[-1].split()[0]
print gateway, ip
#10.64.64.64 106.205.92.100
```

using `regex`:

```
import subprocess, shlex, re
strs =  subprocess.check_output(shlex.split('ip r l'))
match_string = r'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})'
ip = re.search('src '+ match_string, strs).group(1)
gateway = re.search('default via ' + match_string, strs).group(1)
print gateway, ip
#10.64.64.64 106.205.92.100
```

Comment: Khup... Chan... thanks Master..

Comment: You can slightly modify the match string as : match_string = r'(\d{1,3}[.]){3}\d{1,3})'